# How do I import Category Image programmatically in Magento?

Tags: php, api, magento, import, synchronization

I need to import category images from the filesystem in a synchronisation system. For product images there is an API provided by Magento that let me work with images (move, create, delete, etc.) Is there such an API for category images? If not what is your advice?

Comment: could you not use the same API/function on your category images

Answer (score 3):

Upload the image to /media/catalog/category and reference the image filename in your API call.

SOAP API for category.update ‘image’ => ‘filename’

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/47359/

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/catalog_category#catalog_category.create

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but images are on server, there are over 1500 categories, and using SOAP API is overhead in my case